# Skipping columns in a sumproduct formula excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I'm trying to create a formula that counts the number of 1's in rows that contain 1's from another array. It also has to skip certain columns. My formula so far is: `=SUMPRODUCT((B15:B18)*(EXACT(D15:D18,1)+EXACT(F15:G18,1)+EXACT(I15:L18,1)))`but it outputs to N/A or the wrong number. Each of the arrays are the same length but will have different widths. In the example below the output should be 10. It seems to throw errors when there are blank spaces, but my data has many columns that will be blank or sparsley populated.

[image: example formula]

Answer (score 2):

You can try `SUM` function entered as array formula:

```
=SUM(D2:D5*B2:B5,F2:G5*B2:B5,I2:L5*B2:B5)
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to split it into multiple `SUMPRODUCT` formulas. A little bit on the long side, but worked just fine. It also handles more complicated arrays from other functions very well.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B15:B18*EXACT(I15:L18,1))+SUMPRODUCT(B15:B18*EXACT(F15:G18,1))+SUMPRODUCT(B15:B18*EXACT(D15:D18,1))
```

[image: example]